# Is there a way to avoid error Unimplemented type: 4 in vectorTiles?

Tags: caching, openlayers, vector-tiles

I use openLayers 7.4.0 for layer processing.
I find that I am passing layers that I was processing in WMS as rasters to vectorTiles.

I use the following code:

```js
var WMSTileSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: layer.url,
        params: layerParams,
        tileGrid: tileGrid,
    });

var mvtVectorSource = new ol.source.VectorTile({
        url: undefined, // Url is set to undefined to use tileUrlFunction
        params: layerParams,
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
            return WMSTileSource.tileUrlFunction(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection); // Override to use TileWMS tileUrlFunction to load with {x}{y}{z} tile coordenates
        }
    });

layer.vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        source: mvtVectorSource,
        style: function (feature) {
            return setVectorLayerStyle(feature);
        },
        zIndex: layer.index,
        opacity: getLocalLayerOpacity(layer.layerId) ?? layer.opacity,
        visible: true,
        renderBuffer: 0, // Avoid render overlaping features from near tiles
        declutter: true, // Setting declutter to true prevents features to get clipped on tile edges
        preload: Infinity
    });
```

The layers worked fine until I activated the cache in the GeoServer. When I zoom into an area of the map where there are no features the tile request returns:

`java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I understand that it is because the request instead of returning empty features returns a null. However, once this Tile is saved in the cache it returns the empty binary file.

But the problem is that if you try to load many Tiles where the error occurs, openLayers stops responding and doesn't make any more requests.

Do you know if there is anything I can do to fix it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14261  Setting up the WMTS from capacities might help.

Comment: When do you say capacities what do you mean? Do you mean to change TileWMS source format from WMSTileSource to WMTS ? Thank you for your response

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read and though you where using WMTS tilegriid.

Comment: In that case you might need a custom tile load function as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_VectorTile-VectorTile.html which checks for empty data or catches any error in readFeatures, in which case set an empty array of features.

Comment: Hi @Mike, your comment helped me to know about `tileLoadFunction()` . Since, the status code of the `java.lang.NullPointerException` is 200, is difficult to distinguish between requests. It seems that I need to catch the error in GeoServer, although I don't know much about handling error responses . 
Do you know if there is any path that I could follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix without the need for a custom loader you could subclass the format to catch errors when reading features

```
class MVT_with_catch extends MVT {
  readFeatures(source, options) {
    try {
      return super.readFeatures(source, options);
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After @Mike's help teaching me about the existence of the `tileLoadFunction()` function, I was able to resolve the error adding `tileLoadFunction()` as follows:

```js
const mvtVectorSource = new VectorTileSource({
        url: undefined, 
        format: new MVT(),
        tileLoadFunction: function (tile: any, url: string) {
            tile.setLoader(function (extent: any, resolution: any, projection: any): void {
                fetch(url)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            return response.arrayBuffer();
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('Tile request failed with status: ' + response.status);
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(data){
                        const responseText = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data);
                        if (responseText.includes('java.lang.NullPointerException')) {
                            console.warn('Null tile detected, ignoring tile:', url);
                            return;
                        }

                        const format = tile.getFormat();
                        const features = format.readFeatures(data, {
                            extent: extent,
                            featureProjection: projection
                        });
                            tile.setFeatures(features);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error){
                        console.error('Error loading tile:', error);
                    });
            });
        },
        tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord: TileCoord, pixelRatio: number, projection: Projection) {
            return WMSTileSource.tileUrlFunction(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection); 
        }
    });
```

The `tileLoadFunction` checks that the tile response is not null, and if it is, it ignores it.